# AWS Application Load Balancer for ECS 503 errro

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an Application load balancer configured for AWS ECS. The health check endpoint works fine and I can the `200` response but for any other endpoint the load balancer is returning this response:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

All the other posts that have seen talk about health check not working as the cause of the issue but for me the health checks work perfectly find and I can see the message hitting the containers in the logs. Any idea why I am getting this error for other endpoitns?

Comment: Are the target group port and the health check port settings the same? I can see this happening if you have the correct port configured in the health check settings, but the wrong port configured for sending actual traffic to the container.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I had a rule in the target group that was sending the health check to the right port but other traffic was not being redirected correctly. Thanks! do you want to just paste that in the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Done. Also note that there is no "redirect" happening. The traffic is being forwarded/proxied to the targets, not redirected.

Comment: Yep thats what I meant lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the traffic port and the health check port are the same.

I can see this happening if you have the correct port configured in the health check settings, but the wrong port configured for sending actual traffic to the container.